# gghalves Geom_half_boxplot() and Geom_half_point functions returning error when ploting half boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a half-boxplot and half-point plot on the horizontal axis.
To illustrate, the regular boxplot code:

`ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width)) +  facet_grid(Species ~ .)+ geom_boxplot()`

produces the horizontal boxplots but
  `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width)) +  facet_grid(Species ~ .)+geom_half_boxplot()`

results in an error:
`Error in data.frame(x = data$x, xend = data$x, y = c(data$upper, data$lower), arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2, 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gghalves requires a 'y' to compute transformations to halves. The regular geom_boxplot will accept either an x or y, whereas as far as I can tell gghalves requires the 'y'.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghalves)

#You can run this specified as the 'X':
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width)) +  facet_grid(Species~.)+ geom_boxplot()


#Or the 'Y':
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Petal.Width)) +  facet_grid(Species~.)+ geom_boxplot()


#Specifying 'Y' does not give error
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_half_boxplot() +
  geom_half_point()+
  facet_grid(Species~.)+
    coord_flip()  #added flip to make it look more comparable to your original
```